# What is the correct way to deal with hardcoded data in MVVM?

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm

When using the MVVM pattern how are the parts of a view that do not change handled?

As an example the First Activity in an android application has 9 buttons. each button will consist of a label, a drawable image, and an onclick method. Is it correct within MVVM to hard-code the label and image into the XML of the view as they will not change. Or should a model be created for each button with these properties? secondly where should the onclick method be included given that each buttons method will not change and will simply start a new activity?

Comment: Why would you bother to data-bind something that never changes, especially since it is directly related to UI elements and not data or business logic?

Comment: I don't understand your second question.  Wherever you normally put code-behind.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think I have misunderstood mvvm, so onclick methods are included with the view?

Comment: That is my understanding.  In general, if it has to do directly with the UI surface, put it in the View.  If it has to do with data or business logic, put it in the View Model.  Some MVVM systems allow you to put things like Command objects in the ViewModel, which can bind to buttons directly (avoiding event handlers in code-behind).